# Cant save content editable to localstorage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, inventory

I want to save the content editable data to local storage.

Right now if you try to edit the stock table it changes, then when you refresh the page, it goes back to initial value.

Is there a way to do this automatically, without requiring a button to save it? Just by exiting the text box, it should save automatically.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Inventory</title>


  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton|Titan+One" rel="stylesheet">


  <style type="text/css">
   

  table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

#hewrap{
 text-align: center;
}


#he {
 font-family: 'Titan One', cursive;
font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
color: white;
background-color: black;
font-size: 32px;
}


.fi {
 border-radius:5px;
 height: 30px;
}

#btn {
 border-radius: 5px;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: blue;
 color:white;
}

#ftr {
 background-color: black;
}



  </style>



</head>




<body>


 <a class="c-link" href='' onclick='javascript:clearLocal();'>Clear storage</a>

 <div id="hewrap">
 <h1 id="he">Inventory</h1>
</div>

<table id="inventory">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
     <th>Part-#</th>
     <th>Required</th>
     <th>Stock</th>
     <th>Price</th>
     <th>N/A</th>
    </tr>

     <tr id="ftr">
  

 <td><input class="fi" type="text" id="one" placeholder="Description"></td>
 <td><input class="fi" type="text" id="two" placeholder="Part-#"></td>
 <td><input class="fi" type="text" id="three" placeholder="Required"></td>
 <td><input class="fi" type="text" id="four" placeholder="Stock"></td>
 <td><input class="fi" type="text" id="five" placeholder="Price"></td>
 <td><button id="btn" onclick="addRow()">ADD</button></td>


     </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody id="screen">
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
  <script>

   //scribble data



//save
    $( document ).ready(function(){
      $('#screen').html(localStorage.getItem("data"));
      
    });
    function addRow(){

      var str = '<tr class = "boxType"><td>'+$('#one').val()+'</td>\
  <td>'+$('#two').val()+'</td>\
  <td>'+$('#three').val()+'</td>\
  <td id="scribble" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="storeUserScribble(this.id);">'+$('#four').val()+'</td>\
  <td>'+$('#five').val()+'</td>\
</tr>'
      $('#screen').append(str);
      localStorage.setItem("data", $('#screen').html());
    } 

  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
        getUserScribble();
  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: dont mind the storeuser scrible function and get that was me trying something and forgot to delete it

Comment: Do you have any errors displaying in the browser console? Run the page and check, if you don't have any then run the functions and see if any appear. Also check the browsers local storage to ensure the data is being save.

Comment: No except the function that i forgot to delete

Comment: its saving because all the other values save

Comment: the stock td should be contenteditable (which it is) and it should delete the last value of that td and local store the new value

Comment: @GregMyers You need to add an event handler to the element that is being edited (see [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) on the `input` event). Right now, your code is only setting the local storage when you call `addRow`.

Comment: its saving the table data already and it works fine that not the question its that when i edit the content of the stock <td> it should local store the new value

Comment: @GregMyers you need to type `@General_Twyckenham` to alert me that you responded. I'm not sure how my suggestion was unhelpful - please try to explain your *specific* issue more clearly

Comment: @General_Twyckenham when you contenteditable="true" on any element soon as you refresh it takes the value back to the initial text i want it to local store the new data

Comment: Right - because you need to add an event handler (i.e. a function that will respond to the `input` event) that will save the value. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rafikis75/3s4yg1h3/) as an example

Comment: @General_Twyckenham how would i go about writing that for my code it has to be in the var str

Comment: Can I have help?